# Average and RMSE of n x k array

Tags: python, statistics

I have this target array:

```
[ 0.88  0.51  0.55  0.59  0.7 ]
```

and this sample array:

```
[[ 0.4   0.02  0.52  0.44  0.48]
 [ 0.53  0.73  0.13  0.15  0.78]
 [ 0.67  0.27  0.26  0.31  0.17]
 [ 0.37  0.51  0.98  0.2   0.57]]
```

and I would like to produce another array (say 'fns') that will calculate

- row0: the average of each column of the sample array
- row1: the average of each column +1 std deviation
- row2: the average of each column -1 std deviation
- row3: the RMSE of the average to the average for each column

anybody can suggest anything better than nested for statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the nested for loops by using the axis argument available to many `numpy` methods.

```
fns = np.empty((4,sample.shape[1]))
stdv = np.std(sample,axis=0)
fns[0,:] = np.mean(sample,axis=0)
fns[1,:] = fns[0,:] - stdv
fns[2,:] = fns[0,:] + stdv
fns[3,:] = np.sqrt(np.mean((sample - target)**2,axis=0))
```